# Needed help with javascript

Tags: javascript

So guys I am working on a program to like download stuff using javascript. I hav written the following code:

```
function download()
{
   alert("Hello");
   var url='http://somesite/somefile.rar';  
   window.open(url,'Download');
}
```

The code is pretty easy, but is there some other way to download the file using javascript? Also having downloaded the file is there some way to store it locally in the location of our choice, like d-drive? I had come across the javascript file api while searching the web, is it any useful in my scenario? Please help.

Edit: Fixed code formatting

Comment: Please fix your question title. We know it's about "Javascript" as that's what the tags say, and everybody who posts a question wants "help". (In fact, looking at your profile, **all** your question titles are "Need help with X"!!) I took care of the reformatting for you.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible.  It is up to the client where to save files, not you.

Answer (score 0):

Through Javascript, you can only set the file name that you want, but would not be able to access the file system i.e. All the folders, etc..